# Accessing parameters in custom data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using custom data to add a human readable name to my states, like this:

```
.state('data', {
  parent: 'week',
  url: '/data',
  displayName: 'Data Overview',
```

I can then use it in the template like this:

```
<h1>Showing {{$state.current.displayName}}</h1>
```

Which is nice. But now I want to create a route with a parameter, and use that parameter in the displayName:

```
.state('upload', {
  parent: 'week',
  url: '/upload/:level',
  displayName: 'Data Upload for ' + level,
  ...
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax to use access the value of `level` inside the `displayName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` data *(suggested to be placed inside of `data : {}`  - not to be directly on the root state settings)* - are **static** data. So:

> there is **NO** way how to set these data dynamically. E.g. based on the `$stateParams`. These settings are expected to be defined in the `.config()` phase, not evaluated in `.run()`*(in compariosn with others like resolve, templateUrl...)*

See the doc:

#### [Attach Custom Data to State Objects](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)

> You can attach custom data to the state object ***(we recommend using a
>   data property to avoid conflicts).***
>
> ```
> // Example shows an object-based state and a string-based state
> var contacts = { 
>     name: 'contacts',
>     templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
>     data: {
>         customData1: 5,
>         customData2: "blue"
>     }  
> }
> $stateProvider
>   .state(contacts)
>   .state('contacts.list', {
>     templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
>     data: {
>         customData1: 44,
>         customData2: "red"
>     } 
>   })
> ```
>
> With the above example states you could access the data like this:
>
> ```
> function Ctrl($state){
>     console.log($state.current.data.customData1) // outputs 5;
>     console.log($state.current.data.customData2) // outputs "blue";
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Radim, I had a feeling that might be the case. Guess I'll move it into resolve instead.