# Accessing ui-router state controller's data in data section

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I have the state configuration defined in as follows:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
       .state('element', {
        url: '/element',
        templateUrl: 'element.html',
        controller: 'ElementCtrl',
        controllerAs:'ec',
        data: {
            title: 'Element {{ec.name}}',
        }
    })
    .state('element.detail', {
        url: '/detail',
        templateUrl: 'detail.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        controllerAs:'hc',
        data: {
            title: 'Detail {{hc.age}}',
        }
    })
.controller('ElementCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    this.name = "myName";
})
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    this.age = "myName22";
});
```

Here, I want to dynamically determine the data.title field based on the value assigned to the variable in the controller.
Is there a way to do this?(It is better if I do this before the state is activated).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. See more here:

#### [Accessing parameters in custom data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33282078/1679310)

> there is **NO** way how to set these data dynamically. E.g. based on the `$stateParams`. These settings are expected to be defined in the `.config()` phase, not evaluated in `.run()`*(in compariosn with others like resolve, templateUrl...)*

The `data : {}` is intended as a static setting, defined in a config phase.

The way to go is to use **`resolve : {}`**:

#### [Resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.