# Angular ui router, title dynamic

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

How I spend a parameter title of the post, to display the browser's title?

I use pageTitle parameter on my route, but if put directly: slug as a value, not works.

```
.state('posts',{
    url         : '/blog/:slug',
    templateUrl : 'content/templates/single.html',
    controller  : 'SinglePostController',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'title'
    },
    access: {
        requiredLogin: false
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you wanted to put `slug` on your browser title? but then what would be title for the other states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data : {}` setting is static.

see similar:

- [Accessing parameters in custom data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33282078/1679310)

If you want some dynamic feature use **`resolve : {}`**

Some links to examples and Q & A about resolve

- [Angularjs ui-router abstract state with resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27168835/1679310)

EXTEND: A simple *(really naive but working)* example how to use `resolve` and `$rootScope` to manage browser title ([check it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4IHSLzWHsG8W796sytD?p=preview)):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      resolve: {
        'title': ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
          $rootScope.title = "Other title";
        }],
      }
  })
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      resolve: {
        'title': ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
          $rootScope.title = "Title from Parent";
        }],
      }
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
      resolve: {
        'titleFromChild': ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
          $rootScope.title = "Title from Child";
        }],
      }
  })
```

And this could be the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" ng-strict-di>

  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
```

Try it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4IHSLzWHsG8W796sytD?p=preview)

A challenge here is - what to do on navigation from child to parent, but it could be done by moving that setting into controller and work with `$scope.$on('detsroy'`...

Here is [adjusted plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0nj5fkwI3UovNwUSlAW3?p=preview)

```
.state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
      // no resolve, just controller fills the target
  })

.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function ($rootScope, $scope) { 
  var title = $rootScope.title;
  $rootScope.title = "Title from Child";
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){$rootScope.title = title});
}])
```

Comment: Okay, now step as the slug parameter to solve? Direct by stateParams? and set with rootScope?

Comment: @MarcoRiesco, if I do understand your issue, this should be the best asnwer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30268800/1679310

Comment: my issue is on browser title

Comment: Browser title - the best way is $rootScope value.. changed in controller or resolve

Comment: Could you give me an example of how it's done in resolve, with rootscope?

Comment: Yes, I can. See my update. Hope it helps  and shows all the magic we can have with UI-Router. Enjoy it sir ;)